# Spring Kafka thread naming convention

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to understand the Spring Kafka Containter Factory thread naming convention while creating the threads based on concurrency.

I am using `spring-kafka:1.2.1.RELEASE` release and I am finding below details from the documentation.
https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-kafka-dist/1.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_container_thread_naming

> If you don’t provide executors, SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor s are used;
>   these executors create threads with names -C-n (consumer
>   thread) and -L-n (listener thread). For the
>   ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer, the  part of the thread
>   name becomes -m, where m represents the consumer instance. n
>   increments each time the container is started. So, with a bean name of
>   container, threads in this container will be named container-0-C-1 and
>   container-0-L-1, container-1-C-1 etc., after the container is started
>   the first time.

In my app I am seeing threads are getting created `eventListener-0-C-1` , `eventListener-2-C-1` , `eventListener-1-C-1` during the server startup however, while consuming the message on the Listener method I am seeing thread names are `eventListener-0-L-1` , `eventListener-1-L-1` and `eventListener-2-L-1`, which is different. There is no separate executor on my app and its using the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` as part of initial configuration.

Appreciate if someone can provide some internals around this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 2.x is no longer supported. Upgrade to at least 1.3.9. It has a much simpler threading model, thanks to KIP-62. The latest release is 2.2.3 and has many improved features over 1.x.

With the old threading model there were two threads per consumer. One to poll and one to invoke the listener.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Our Kafka broker version is 0.10.0.*. After seeing the spring Kafka compatibility matrix at https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka, I am seeing the latest Spring for Apache Kafka Version support is 1.2.x, and the next spring Kafka version 1.3.x is taking Kafka client as 0.11.0.x, 1.0.x. This is the reason I have chosen the spring Kafka 1.2.1 based on Kafka client 0.10.0.*. Can version 1.3.9 will support for Kafka client 0.10.0.*?

Comment: Yes, the 0.11 clients (used with 1.3.x) are completely compatible with an 0.10 broker - see the [confluent matrix, which is also linked from the project page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix). `Broker 0.10.0 : Java: clients <= 0.10.0 or >= 0.10.2`. However, I strongly recommend you upgrade to a more modern broker. The current broker is 2.1.0.

Comment: Sure. I will bring this point to upgrade the Kafka broker. I have upgraded the broker and process of verifying existing business functionalities which I expect to work as before.

Comment: I thought to follow up with one additional question in this thread. I upgraded the version and now seeing the threads are with ```C``` which are ```eventListener-0-C-1``` , ```eventListener-1-C-1``` and ```eventListener-2-C-1```. My question is when the counter gets increased 0/1/2-C-1. Is it happens when internally re- balances happens, which says after start/stop. In my scenario I am not stopping consumer when not used, so, wondering if this gets increased as part of start/stop of listener threads. please correct me if my understanding is wrong.